# Use PVC connector with flexible conduit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, security

I need to run some Cat5e cable outdoors for POE cameras. I want to run them through a flexible conduit. There's a place where I would need a 3 way (T piece connector). There isn't a 3 way for the type of conduit that I have (Liquidtight non metallic). Would a PVC 3 way work and how would I seal it? Do I even need to seal since it's the sun that I should be most worry about right?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you using LFNC-A or LFNC-B?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel OP posted a picture of the package in [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119890/securing-conduit-to-hardieplank).

Comment: Can you put a box at this T-point?

Comment: If you'd simply purchase exterior-rated cat5e (which you'll need anyway to get wet-rated Cat5e - all exterior conduits are defined as wet, and they usually live up to the definition) you don't need conduit at all - it has a black sunlight resistant and waterproof jacket, as well as internal waterproofing (either grease or dry swellable gel type.) Use the same sort of cable clips the cable-TV folks do and you'd be done...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  A pull box? I think so. The reason for all this is because I got one wire going to the right and another one going to the left. After that I have to run them upward.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I just didn't want to spend the money buying those outdoor cables. There cables came with the camera system.

Comment: If you could/can return the liquidtight conduit it would probably pay for proper outdoor cable. If you use indoor cable in a conduit, it will fail due to water intrusion; probably not immediately, but eventually you'll be replacing it as it is not designed for use in wet locations.